# O parâmetro que uso não está retornando nada quando executo a proc no test pela package

Tags: oracle

Tenho uma procedure que quando realizo a consulta nela tenho os resultados corretos. Porém, quando passo via parâmetros no Debug do plsql ela não considera o campo em questão.

O campo é o mesmo tipo da tabela (varchar2) e os outros funcionam, esse não.

```
PROCEDURE REL_GERACAO_ARQUIVO_REPASSE (DADOS OUT T_CURSOR,
                                            DATA_CREDITO      IN NVARCHAR2,             
                                            DATA_REPASSE      IN NVARCHAR2,     
                                            EMPRESA       IN NUMBER,        
                                            **REFERENCIA**    IN VARCHAR2) IS       

    BEGIN                                
        OPEN DADOS FOR                   

    SELECT distinct 
     ('01/'||lpad(result.REFERENCIA,2,1)||
        '/'||substr(result.REFERENCIA,3,6)||
        lpad(1,10,0)||
        lpad(result.COD_EMPRS,10,0)||
        lpad(vfss.num_plbnf,10,0)|| 
        DATA_CREDITO || --- Parâmetro data de Crédito  (Digitar a data entre caspeta simples)
        DATA_REPASSE ||  --- Parâmetro data do Repasse (Digitar a data entre caspeta simples)
        lpad(RESULT.COD_VERBA,10,0)||
        lpad(abs(SUM(RESULT.ValorVerba)*100000000),21,0)||
        lpad(abs(SUM(RESULT.vlr_acerto)*100000000),21,0)) AS "Geração - Arquivo de Repasse"

        FROM 
        att.verba_fss vfss,
        (
            SELECT D.ID_MODULO,
                D.ID_ROTINA,
                D.REFERENCIA,
                D.COD_EMPRS, 
                E.NOM_ABRVO_EMPRS, 
                E.NOM_RZSOC_EMPRS, 
                V.COD_GRUPO_FINANCEIRO, 
                V.COD_SUBGRUPO_FINANCEIRO,
                D.NUM_RGTRO_EMPRG, 
                V.ORDEM ORDEM3, 
                D.COD_VERBA, 
                VER.DCR_VERBA, 
                DECODE(V.CRED_DEB,'C',1,-1) * D.VLR_DESCONTO AS ValorVerba, 
                0 as vlr_acerto,
                V.CRED_DEB      
                FROM INT_FCO.TB_SCA_IMP_DESCONTO D
                INNER JOIN INT_FCO.TB_SCR_SUBGRUPO_FINANC_VERBA V ON (D.COD_VERBA = V.COD_VERBA and v.fl_autopatroc = 0 )
                INNER JOIN ATT.EMPRESA E ON (D.COD_EMPRS = E.COD_EMPRS)
                INNER JOIN ATT.VERBA VER ON (D.COD_VERBA = VER.COD_VERBA)
                WHERE D.ID_MODULO = 6
                    AND D.ID_ROTINA in (10,12)
                    AND D.FL_REPASSE = 1
            ) RESULT

        WHERE RESULT.COD_EMPRS = EMPRESA --- Parâmetro empresa
            AND RESULT.REFERENCIA = **REFERENCIA** --- Parâmetro mês ano (mmyyyy)
            AND RESULT.COD_VERBA >=90000
            AND RESULT.COD_VERBA = vfss.num_vrbfss
        GROUP BY result.REFERENCIA,
        RESULT.COD_EMPRS,
        RESULT.COD_VERBA,
        vfss.num_plbnf
    ;

 END;
```

Comment: Como está o codigo do seu test?

Comment: David, descobri que era o nome do parâmetro que estava dando conflito. Provavelmente por usar 'REFERENCIA' em outros pontos da query. Valeu

Comment: poderia postar sua `procedure` como resposta? vlw :)